# Android NDK: Handling and creating input events inside android_main function

Tags: android, c++, c, input, android-ndk

Android by default handles input events in `app_handle_event` but is it possible to do it from inside `android_main` with standalone `AInputEvent` or something like that?

Also, Is it possible to create standalone `AInputEvent` for each input method, Like Joysticks but inside `android_main` function?

And thanks!